# In a ring, how do we prove that a * 0 = 0?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, rngs

In a ring, I was trying to prove that for all $a$, $a0 = 0$.

But I found that this depended on a lemma, that is, for all $a$ and $b$, $a(-b) = -ab = (-a)b$.

I am wondering how to prove these directly from the definition of a ring.

Many thanks!

Comment: You can start with $0 + 0 = 0$, multiply both sides by $a$, and distribute on the left.  Then subtract $a\cdot 0$ from both sides.

Comment: @littleO You should put that into song form.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Proceed like this

- $a0 = a(0+0)$, property of $0$.
- $a0 = a0 + a0$, property of distributivity.
- Thus $a0+ (-a0) = (a0 + a0) +(-a0)$, using existence of additive inverse.
- $a0+ (-a0) = a0 + (a0 + (-a0))$ by associativity.
- $0 = a0 + 0$ by properties of additive inverse.
- Finally $0 = a0$ by property of $0$.

Your lemma is also true, you can now prove it easily:

Just note that $ab +a(-b)= a(b + (-b))= a0= 0$.

Comment: Thanks, it is very useful that you listed the properties.  It seems to me that we did not use additive closure, multiplicative associativity, or multiplicative identity.

Comment: Therefore, we get this propety in something even more general than Rngs.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes one does not use all properties, and I think you are right in that it is also true in non-associateive algebras.

Comment: @mareoraft What is "additive closure"?

Comment: @Filippo Post a new question on this website asking "What is the 'additive closure' property in the context of rings?" and somebody should help you.

Comment: @mareoraft As far as I know this simply means that the sum of two elements of the ring is an element of the ring, I would just appreciate a confirmation that this is what you mean because the comment really surprised me.

Comment: @Filippo Yes, that is what is what I mean.  Typically we first define addition as a binary operation (which includes closure in its definition), then we define a group, then we define a ring.  So if you want to be really careful, you may have to go back and investigate these definitions.  In my second comment I was using the term rng to refer to a non-unital ring (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_%28algebra%29).  Have a great day!

Comment: @mareoraft Thank you for the explanation and the link  and have a great day, too :)

Answer (score 9):

$a\cdot0=a\cdot0+0$ (Additive identity) 
$=a\cdot0+(a+(-a))$ (Additive inverse) 
$=(a\cdot0+a)+(-a)$ (Associativity) 
$=(a\cdot0+a\cdot1)+(-a)$ (Multiplicative identity) 
$=a\cdot(0+1)+(-a)$ (Distributivity) 
$=a\cdot1+(-a)$ (Additive identity) 
$=a+(-a)$ (Multiplicative identity) 
$=0$ (Additive inverse)

Then, we can prove that $-a=(-1)\cdot a$: 
If $a+(-1)\cdot a=0$, then $(-1)\cdot a=-a$ (there's a unique additive inverse element) 
$a+(-1)\cdot a=a\cdot1+a\cdot(-1)=a\cdot(1+(-1))=a\cdot0=0$ (we used the first theorem)

So, the first theorem is necessary to prove the second one, but not conversely.

Comment: really nice and neat.

Answer (score 8):

$a \cdot 0 = a \cdot (0 + 0) = a \cdot 0 + a \cdot 0$