# Zero ring explanation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we have a ring $R$, $r \in R$ and we make the additive and multiplicative identities coincide $1 = 0$. How does then the following proof of it being the zero ring hold: $$r = 1r = 0r = 0$$

My confusion arises from the fact that in the definition(axioms) of the ring there is no property that says that the binary operation of multiplication with a $0$ will produce a $0$.

I might have this all wrong, can anyone clear this up?

Comment: One can prove that the multiplication with $0$ in the ring gives you $0$ as answer. You could look it up at e.g Wikipedia

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: I can even provide you a stackexchange link, here you go: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483716/in-a-ring-how-do-we-prove-that-a-0-0

Answer (score 3):

You can show this is the case since:
$$
0r = (0+0)r = 0r + 0r \\
\implies 0r - 0r = 0r + 0r - 0r \\
\implies 0 = 0r
$$

Alternatively:
$$
r = 1r = (1+0)r = 1r + 0r = r + 0r \\
r = 1r = (0 + 1)r = 0r + 1r = 0r + r
$$
So $0r$ is indeed the additive identity of the ring, thus it's equal to $0$ (since there can only be one identity of a group).

Comment: I dont understand this. Why does this show that $0r=0$?

Comment: You can see from this proof that the element $0r$ is the identity in the operation $+:R\times R \to R$, thus it's the zero of the ring. I'll add another proof that shows this a little bit more clearly.