# My proof for $|R|=1$ if and only if $1=0$ where $R$ is a ring with unity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm reading Dummit's book. (Abstract Algebra, 3ed, p224)
Now I want to prove the following.
Suppose $R$ is a ring with 1.
Then, $|R|=1$($R$ is a *trivial ring*, [or the *zero ring* in the book]) if and only if $1=0$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ : Since $0\in R$, $1\in R$ and $|R|=1$, it is immediate that $1=0$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ : Suppose that $a\in R$.
Then $a=a\cdot1=a\cdot0\stackrel{(*)}=0$.
Thus $R=\{0\}$.

But how can I justify $(*)$?
Does that follow immediately from the definition of a ring with unity?

Or, is there another proof for $(\Leftarrow)$?

Comment: $a0=a(0+0)=a0+a0\rightarrow a0=0$

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. Actually I've seen it before, but forgot now. Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome.

Comment: Should I close this thread? or... What should I do? Is the question too trivial?

Comment: @govin The question is ok as it stands. However, this is a standard fact and I there are already answers somewhere on this side (for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483716/in-a-ring-how-do-we-prove-that-a-0-0)). So make sure to search for those first the next time.

Comment: @mrtaurho Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments already answer the question. However, I will just post this answer to close the thread.

We know that $0+0=0$ as $0$ is the additive neutral element and that $a(0+0)=a0+a0$ by distributivity. Putting these together gives us the following:

$$a0=a(0+0)=a0+a0 \implies (a0+a0)-a0=a0-a0 \implies a0=0$$

We know that $a0+(-a0)=a0-a0=0$ as every element $r$ in a ring has an additive inverse and one can show (and I would advise you doing so) that this inverse is in fact given by $-r=(-1)r$.